# Is the MessageId for an SNS message the same as the corresponding SQS MessageId?

Tags: amazon-sqs, amazon-sns

I post a message to SNS using `boto3` like so:

```
response = sns.publish(
        TopicArn=arn, Message=json.dumps(body_dict), MessageAttributes=message_attributes,
    )
logger.debug("Sent Event to SNS. MessageId: %s", name, response["MessageId"])
```

I have an SQS queue subscribed to that SNS topic. Will the MessageId for the corresponding SQS message in the SQS queue be the same as the MessageId returned by SNS?

Answer (score 3):

I tested this and the answer is no. The SQS message_id for an SNS message will be different from the SNS message_id.